# Как задать диапазон значений?

Tags: if

Здрасьте! Я не кодер вообще ни разу, попросили помочь и вижу следующее:

```
if (((a>1) and (a=<5)) and ((b>2) and (b<10))) then
```

Не уверен, что она даже будет работать, да и на мой взгляд юзверя выглядит крайне криво. Не будет ли коду плохо от такого количества 'and' и есть ли варианты задать диапазоны другим способом? Просьба максимально пояснять ответ :)

Comment: @Rasul: Вы изменили смысл вопроса, кстати.

Comment: да нормально `bool cond = (a >1 && a =< 5) && (b > 2 && b < 10); if (cond) { }` .... остальные решения будут все равно не лучше, если только таких проверок в `if` не ожидается большое количество

Comment: Ох, немного сложный сервис для обывателя с этими правками. Полностью моя строка выглядит так:
`if (((a>1) and (a=<5)) and ((b>2) and (b<10))) then
{c=15};`

Мне интересно, как можно изменить саму конструкцию диапазонов на менее варварскую и верно ли они заданы у меня(будут ли работать).

upd: да, проверок по if много и они идут друг за другом. Суть кода в том, чтобы при разных значениях a  и b давать определенное значение c.

Comment: @JackEnfield: То есть у вас именно `and` и `then`?

Comment: Да, именно так. upd: я не кодер, повторюсь, и хз можно ли их заменить на что-то :)

Comment: @VladD Я не изменил смысл вопроса потому-что автор хочет показать вопрос в виде C# смысл не изменён а вопрос неправильно определён. внимательно смотрите !

Comment: Вы лучше скажите, есть ли варианты изменить способ выделения диапазона и работает ли указанный мной вариант, т.к. проверить возможности нет.

Comment: Как это нет возможности проверить? Есть же онлайн-компиляторы! ideone.com например.

Comment: Вообще если у вас реально шарп, а не паскаль, то все скобки можно выбросить, так как толку от них никакого, останется просто: `if (a>1 && a=<5 && b>2 && b<10) { }` В паскале скобки нужны, т.к. там операции `and`/`or`/`>`/`<`/и т.д. имеют одинаковый приоритет и код вообще не скомпилируется. Ну и, конечно, есть нюанс если вместо `a` и `b` там фактически стоят вызовы (тяжеловесных) функций

Comment: Правку откатил, т.к. она вредная, не понятно что автор имел ввиду и если у него реально шарп, то может иметь значение там `&` или `&&`, @Rasul

Comment: просто здесь не может определить автор порядок. здесь уверенностью && сформулирован.

Comment: @Rasul: Автор не выдумал `and` и `then`. Это значит, что его код не компилируется, и в этом проблема. Ваша правка меняет смысл вопроса, теперь в нём этой проблемы нет.

Comment: @JackEnfield: Это даже не скомпилируется. В C# нет ни `and`, ни `then`. У вас точно язык C#, а не Паскаль?

Comment: Фокус в том, что я не в курсе :)
Дали файл на посмотреть, а там предположил. Значит, это таки Паскаль. И если верно понял, то в Паскале другого варианта диапазона нет, так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это в реальности не C#, а Паскаль, то отрезки можно проверять проще:

```
if (a in [2..5]) and (b in [3..9]) then ...
```

Это, разумеется, для случая, когда `a` и `b` — целочисленные переменные. Работает для случая, когда размер диапазона не более 255 элементов.

---

В некоторых диалектах Паскаля можно [создавать функции расширения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25128563/276994), там проверку диапазона можно объявить как такую вот функцию.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно еще вопрос для общего развития: как быть, если числа не целые?

Comment: @JackEnfield: Только двойным сравнением, насколько я понимаю.